# MobileFirst heartbeat call in background with screen lock

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Inside WLClient.h mention this comment.

> - @note The client sends a heartbeat signal to the server only when
>     the application is in the foreground. When the application is sent to
>     the background, the client stops sending heartbeat signals. The client
>     resumes sending heartbeat signals when the application is brought to
>     the foreground again.

I set my setHeartBeatInterval to 420. which is default. But when the app goes into background with lock screen. It still will call the heartbeat after 420 seconds. Then my app crash.

Is there anyway to disable the heartbeat call when the app goes into background?

Thanks so much =)

Comment: Please provide the version of MFP and the fix level on which you are seeing this issue.

Comment: It is MFP7.1 version, within that 3 minutes background task in my app. It will crash while the 7 minutes interval hit, it will call the heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

On MFP 7.1, we are not seeing any issue with heartbeat in both iOS 9.3.5 and iOS 10. In both iOS versions, when the app is in background(by pressing home or behind the lock screen), the heartbeats are paused and are not sent. 
We see this behavior in the latest v7.1 iFix version and on iOS devices running iOS9.3.5 and iOS10.

However, on iOS10 simulator, we can see couple of heartbeat requests are made when the screen is locked or if the home button is pressed. But, even here, when the app is resumed, there is no crash. This seems to be a behavior with iOS 10 simulator only.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I notice that once i add on beginBackgroundTaskWithName funtion. Then heartbeat will call in background. But it is not consistent to replicate this issues. Sometimes can replicate. Sometimes cant.